# jQuery replace DIV to INPUT and vice versa

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am implementing an inline edit kind of functionality.

So initially a date label (say 05/01/1999) will be displayed and on click of it, it would be replaced with an input box with the same value (05/01/1999). Now user can select any date using the jQuery UI date picker and on select of any date (say 05/01/2005), I would again show a label (05/01/2005)

Currently I am using the below code;

```
$(document).on("click",".editableDateTxt", function () {
    var currElmModelAttr = $(this).attr('data-model-attr');
    var input = $('<input />', {'type': 'text','name':currElmModelAttr, 'style':'width:100px','class':'datePicker', 'value': $(this).html()});
    var parent = $(this).parent();
    parent.append(input);
    $(this).remove();
    input.datepicker().focus();
});
```

What is the best way to implement the same?

Now here is the crucial point: I am using **jQuery UI datepicker**, which uses the jQuery data() internally. So I do not want to loose it while jumping from div > input and vice versa.

How can I modify the above code to consider that the jQuery data() info stays?

### Updated code

```
 var MyView = BaseModalView.extend({
            el: "#myModalContainer",
            initialize: function() {
                var self = this;
            
            },

render: function() {
                var self = this,
                    $el = $(self.el);
                
                $el.find(".datePicker").datepicker();
                self.initEventListeners();
            },

initEventListeners: function() {
                var self = this, 
                    $el = $(self.el);

        var $this;
$(document).on("click", ".editableDateTxt", function () {
    var currElmModelId = $(this).attr('data-model-id');
    var currElmModelAttr = $(this).attr('data-model-attr');
    $this = $(this);
    var input = $('<input />', {
            'type': 'text',
            'name': currElmModelAttr,
            'data-model-id': currElmModelId, 
            'data-model-attr': currElmModelAttr,
            'style': 'width:100px',
            'class': 'datePicker',
            'value': $(this).text()
    });
    $(this).replaceWith(input);
    input.datepicker({
        onSelect: function (date) {
            $this.text(date);
            input.replaceWith($this);
            // input.blur();
        }
    }).focus();
    $(document).on("blur change", "input", function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            var value = input.val();
            $this.text(value);
            input.replaceWith($this);
        }, 100);

    });

});

}
```

Comment: Can you post a fiddle and your html.

Comment: actually it is part of my web app...so difficult to post it..let me try...

Comment: I think you are probably over complicating this. Must you really swap these elements? Why not just have one display and one not but leave both on the page?

Comment: could u just post a rough code of what u r talking about ?

Answer (score 6):

You can do that better swapping with **[`replaceWith()`](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/)**

```
$(document).on("click", ".editableDateTxt", function () {
    var currElmModelAttr = $(this).attr('data-model-attr');
    var $this = $(this);
    var input = $('<input />', {
        'type': 'text',
        'name': currElmModelAttr,
        'style': 'width:100px',
        'class': 'datePicker',
        'value': $(this).text()
    });
    $(this).replaceWith(input);
    input.datepicker({
        onSelect: function (date) {
            $this.text(date);
            input.replaceWith($this);
            console.log(date);
        }
    })

});
```

### [Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Gr4yy/4/)

Also, I suggest, you hide/show the elements, which would be better in this case, instead of creating and swapping elements every time.

Comment: and i think i'll not have onSelect: function (date) {} inside click of editableDateTxt ....would have that replace handled in change of .datePicker

Comment: so what is the correct way? can u post on fiddle something which works with click, change, blur

Comment: You have to use onselect, on change and on blur wont work on '.datepicker` wait i'm working on a solution.

Comment: Thx....butit would be really great and appeciated if u can update the fiddle so that i get a clear working picture...i'll accept the answer and close...coz i need that on blur, the date picker should hide and show back as label text

Comment: or are u saying it is not possible to have all at once (click,change blur) ?

Comment: See, the Datepicker plugin gives datepicker value to input after the blur in fired. So the blur,change event won't get the changed date

Comment: ok..but how do I hide the picker input on blur and show back the date as label ?

Comment: i m getting 
TypeError: e is undefined (when i select any date and also when i click out i.e. blur)

Comment: Actually i don't know why...but when i select any date..it has the div element in $this , but after it fires input.replaceWith($this); ...nothing is visible in the div

Comment: is the $this global? Settimeout is just for getting values. Post a fiddle which is giving error

Comment: I have defined it outsde $(document).on("click", ".editableDateTxt", ...) so it does seem to be global

Comment: Hmm...I know the fiddle is working...but not sure why it is not working for me....Actually i cannot post the exact thing i m working on...since it is a complete Backbone View inside of which i have this code....

Comment: Have you removed all the other events? Your previous blur and change?

Comment: when i debug i get $this as the div element with correct values....but then the div itself disappears from the DOM completely..like gets deleted...not sure somthing inside setTimeout or what ?

Comment: I have updated the code in my original question to include more of the view code...pls ignore any braces issues...i have just copied it at random to give a more detailed picture...

Comment: In that case, it gives me an error...uncaught exception: Missing instance data for this datepicker (on date select)...

Comment: Here is what...i increased the setTimeout delay to 1000...then i select a date...the selected date appears as label after 1 sec and then just disappears....

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simpler version, as suggested by @Shaunak D, using the basic `hide()` and `show()`.

^_^ [**jsfiddle sample**](http://jsfiddle.net/PVVdu/4/)

Html code:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="lbl"></div>
<input type='text' id="date-picker" />
```

Js codes:

```
$('#lbl').html('2014-01-01');
$('#date-picker').hide();
$('#date-picker').datepicker({
   onSelect: function(date) {
        $('#lbl').html(date);
        $(this).hide();
        $('#lbl').show();
    }
});

$('#lbl').click(function(){
  //alert();
  $(this).hide();
  $('#date-picker').show();

});
```

Comment: The best way to do this is to use a readonly input field with the date picker. Is there any reason behind using the div and replacing with input field?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to use a readonly input field with the date picker. Is there any reason behind using the div and replacing with input field?